# Interpreting CI, standard error and estimates

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

I'm running into interpreting some of my results.
[image: Results ketone bodies models]

I am fairly new to statistics, and I've watched a lot of youtube videos and googled even more, but I don't know if I'm interpreting this correctly. The outcome variable "ketone bodies" was log transformed in the models, hence the back transformed and log transformed results.

My interpretation:

- Confidence intervals that exclude zeroes --> significant independent variables association to dependent variable
- Big standard error --> struggle with understanding this, I find the CI rather small, so if I'm correct, 95% of the datapoints are whitin that CI, and then the other 5 % is uhm, in for example (LM Eating -3) upper CI limit + SE or lower CI limit - SE? So: 0.99975785 + 1.00094635? Or 0.99605748  - 1.00094635? And then does that say anything about my data?
- Estimates are positive so there is a positive association?

That's all I can understand, am I doing this correctly?

Furthermore, I checked for linearity with qq plots:
[image: qq plot example]

I have found that this is a (sligthly?) tailed qq plot, however, that is all I can find when I search for tailed qq plots. What does this main? Should I correct for this in the model? Is this the reason for the big standard error? Or is this linear enough?

I really hope these questions are appropriate and clear, and someone can help me with this.

Comment: log transforming and "back transforming" doesn't quite work as you think. If the model is reasonably linear in log transformed form, but not without, the "back transformed" parameters cannot be interpreted in the standard linear regression framework, neither can the confidence intervals, and surely not the standard errors. You can only meaningfully "back transform" predicted values.

Comment: Confidence intervals are not about percentages of the data points but rather about the sampling distribution of the estimates, i.e., you'd expect the CI (computed from the sampling distribution and its standard error) to catch the true parameter in 95% of the cases, but if you fit your model for log transformed data, this interpretation holds for the parameters corresponding to the model for those data only; there are no meaningful "true back transformed parameters".

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for your quick reply. Hmm okay, i was told to back transform the results by my teacher, and display them in my results as well. But now in fact you are telling me that the back transformed results don't mean anything? Sooo, i don't really need to mention them? Only the original log transformed results have value?

Comment: I have no idea what your teacher wants and no opinion on what you should mention or not. Obviously this also depends on the understanding of those who read your stuff. What I'm saying is that back-transformed parameter values are not valid parameter values of any well-defined model (some may interpret them in some way but that doesn't seem very sensible to me), and therefore back-transformed CIs are not proper CIs for anything. What you can back-transform is fitted values, residuals, and predictions for graphical display (I'm not saying you *should* do that though).